# Difference between a "self-serving individual" and "self-centered individual"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

Is being "self-serving" the same as being "self-centered"?  While looking for an answer to this question, I saw [this previous question on the difference between "selfish" and "self-centered"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43645/difference-between-selfish-and-self-centered).  I generally agree with the top three answers in that question (i.e. the answers provided by @FeralOink @Bill and @mozen), but want to know if and how "self-serving" differs from "self-centered."

Are the connotations or actual meanings different, or are the words essentially interchangeable?  I think "self-serving" implies something about purpose, while "self-centered" implies something about focus, but I am not sure, and I have not been able to flesh out the difference in a satisfying way.

Comment: A *self-centred* person usually means someone who is excessively preoccupied with their own concerns, but that doesn't imply they actually have the good judgement (or indeed, *ability*) to act in ways that serve their own best interests. Self-centredness may be at the root of behavioural problems leading to anorexia or self-harm, for example - but few would say these are *self-serving* behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what jumps out in my mind:

A self-centered person thinks about himself a lot, and possible talks about himself a lot.  He/she may have a hard time relating to other people and being empathetic.

A self-serving person continuously does things that helps himself, possibly at the expense of others.  For example a self-serving politician will do anything to get elected.